# combining 2 lists with score in python

Tags: python

hi i want to combine 2 lists with python and i want a score for each combination.

```
from itertools import permutations, repeat

list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]
combined = []

for a in list1:
    new_list = []
    for b in list2:
        new_list.append([a, b])
    combined.append(new_list)

print (combined)
```

at the end i need a output like this, the score is based from the values behind. a1 = 0.5, b1 = 0.5 score or a1 b1 = 0.5 * 0.5

```
'a1', 'b1' , 0.25
'a1', 'b2' , 0.20
...
...
...
'a3', 'b3' , 0.16
```

no sorting needed. any idea ?

Comment: How do you get the score?

Comment: hi no need for a sorted list simply combine the values from the 2 lists and add the score behind them

Comment: Why are your lists like that? If the information is supposed to be paired, you should use lists of tuples, e.g. `list1 = [("a1", 0.5), ("a2" , 0.4) , ("a3", 0.4)]`

Comment: You can't use `for a in list1:` because the list alternates names and scores, and that doesn't distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt, I am assuming things like 'a1' and 'b1' will always be at even indices for this method:

```
def get_combination(list1, list2, idx1, idx2):
    return list1[idx1], list2[idx2], round(list1[idx1+1] * list1[idx2+1],2)


list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]

combined =[]

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    for j in range(0, len(list1), 2):
           combined.append(get_combination(list1,list2, i,j))


print(combined)
```

Output:

```
[('a1', 'b1', 0.25), ('a1', 'b2', 0.2), ('a1', 'b3', 0.2), ('a2', 'b1', 0.2), ('a2', 'b2', 0.16), ('a2', 'b3', 0.16), ('a3', 'b1', 0.2), ('a3', 'b2', 0.16), ('a3', 'b3', 0.16)]
```

Comment: Why not `range(0, len(list1), 2)` so you don't need to test if it's odd or even?

Comment: Good point, it is because I forgot. I have changed that.

Comment: You wouldn't have to check for the odd/even

Comment: Yes I have changed that now. Changed the iterator but forgot to remove the condition

Answer (score 0):

Here is one basic solution:

```
list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]

result = [[list1[index1], list2[index2], list1[index1 + 1] * list2[index2 + 1]] for index1 in range(0, len(list1), 2) for index2 in range(0, len(list2), 2)]
```

Comment: hi your code give me this

[['a1', 'b1', 0.25], ['a1', 'b2', 0.2], ['a1', 'b3', 0.15], ['a2', 'b1', 0.2], ['a2', 'b2', 0.16000000000000003], ['a2', 'b3', 0.12], ['a3', 'b1', 0.15], ['a3', 'b2', 0.12], ['a3', 'b3', 0.09]]
but it works

Comment: @SvenPfeiffer I don't know why it gives you wrong answers. Everything works fine on my laptop. And about leading zeros, use `round` function as in Richard K Yu's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically already there. If the number is the score, then it would be:

```py
list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]
combined = []

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    a = list1[i]
    ascore = list1[i + 1]
    new_list = []
    for j in range(0, len(list2), 2):
        b = list2[j]
        bscore = list2[j+1]
        new_list.append([a, b, round(ascore*bscore, 5)])
        j += 2
    combined.append(new_list)

print (combined)
```

If you want to flatten the nested list, add this at the bottom:

```py
import itertools

flattened = list(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*combined)))
print(flattened)
```

EDIT:
For a third, fourth, fifth list, continue nesting the loops:

```py
list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]
list3 = ["c1", 0.5, "c2", 0.4, "c3", 0.4]
combined = []

for a_iter in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    a = list1[a_iter]
    ascore = list1[a_iter + 1]
    new_list = []
    for b_iter in range(0, len(list2), 2):
        b = list2[b_iter]
        bscore = list2[b_iter+1]
        for c_iter in range(0, len(list3), 2):
            c = list3[c_iter]
            cscore = list3[c_iter + 1]
            # more nested loops here
            new_list.append([a, b, c, round(ascore*bscore*cscore, 5)])  #put in innermost loop
    combined.append(new_list)

print (combined)
```

Comment: if i want to add a third list
list3 = ["c1", 0.5, "c2", 0.4 , "c3", 0.4] what the solution for this ?

Comment: Basically, you would keep adding a nested loop for each list, and add it to the append call. To flatten, you would have to add another `itertools.chain` call or use a different method.

Comment: I edited the answer for any number of lists

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `itertools`:

```py
import itertools
list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]

packed_list1 = [(list1[i], list1[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)]
packed_list2 = [(list2[i], list2[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)]

product = itertools.product(packed_list1, packed_list2) # contains 2-tuples where each element is a 2-tuple
result = [(first[0], second[0], first[1] * second[1]) for first, second in product]
print(result)
```

You could condense all of these into a massive one-line list comprehension if you really wanted to, but for readability I've separated everything out onto separate lines.

Comment: thank you very much,, if i want to add a third list i simply have to add packet list3 ? and is there a easy way to get the output row by row

Comment: Yes, and you'd need to modify the `product` and `result` initializations to work with 3-tuples rather than 2-tuples. For your other question, do you mean printing one tuple per row?

Answer (score 0):

got it to work, thanks for the help here as 3 list version

```
import itertools
list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2" , 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4 , "b3", 0.4]
list3 = ["c1", 0.5, "c2", 0.4 , "c3", 0.4]

combined = []

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    a = list1[i]
    ascore = list1[i + 1]
    new_list = []
    for j in range(0, len(list2), 2):
        b = list2[j]
        bscore = list2[j+1]
        for k in range(0, len(list3), 2):
            c = list3[k]
            cscore = list3[k+1]
            new_list.append([a, b, round(ascore*bscore*cscore, 5)])
            k += 2
        combined.append(new_list)

print (combined)
flattened = list(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*combined)))
print(flattened)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The itertools functionality you are looking for is called `product`

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2", 0.4, "a3", 0.4]
list2 = ["b1", 0.5, "b2", 0.4, "b3", 0.4]

# suggestion: format your list in a dict 
# such that your keys 'a1', 'a2', ... and the values are actually associated
dict1 = dict(zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2]))
dict2 = dict(zip(list2[::2], list2[1::2]))

# then you can use product to get all combinations of pairings
# and construct the final list with a neat list comprehension
combined = [(k1, k2, dict1[k1]*dict2[k2]) for k1,k2 in product(dict1,dict2)]

print(combined)
[('a1', 'b1', 0.25), ('a1', 'b2', 0.2), ('a1', 'b3', 0.2), ('a2', 'b1', 0.2), ('a2', 'b2', 0.16000000000000003), ('a2', 'b3', 0.16000000000000003), ('a3', 'b1', 0.2), ('a3', 'b2', 0.16000000000000003), ('a3', 'b3', 0.16000000000000003)]
```

Explanation of the dict construction:

```
>>> list1 = ["a1", 0.5, "a2", 0.4 , "a3", 0.4]
# the even indices hold the keys, the odd indices hold the values
>>> list1[::2] # slicing the list with a step size of 2 gives all the keys
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>> list1[1::2] # same but starting from 1 gives all the values
[0.5, 0.4, 0.4]
>>> dict(zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2])) 
# zip up the keys and values and construct a dict
{'a1': 0.5, 'a2': 0.4, 'a3': 0.4}
```

Example of the `product`

```
>>> list(product(['a1','a2'], ['b1','b2']))
[('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2')]
```